# How to change user page content without refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react js app with a video player window, using Firebase database.
I have an admin panel that can change the url of the video shown.

I want when the admin change the video displayed, the video shown of users in the other side, changed without refresh rhe page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way using Firebase.
[Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

`onSnapshot()` function

> You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WebSockets (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). The client will listen for changes and change state inside the component.